# How to link an element on a page with Infinite Scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, infinite-scroll

I have a page that contains a container with infinite scroll that loads articles.

The question is, how can I link a specific article, when its `div` isn't loaded into the DOM until you start scrolling?

I want the link to point to an `id` of the `div` that is loaded using infinite scroll.

Unfortunately, nothing I did worked so far.

Comment: It would be appreciated that you post some code and explain _what_ did you do so far.

Answer (score 0):

If the element is not yet in the HTML of the page, you will not be able to directly link to it. You will have to find an alternative solution, maybe something like using JavaScript interaction that loads more pages until it finds the desired article.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried to do, but it seems really hard to implement, I basically need to scroll until InfiniteScroll loads the div I need, then check if the id of the div is equal to the hash that's used to link this post. Unfortunately, I'm not yet that proficient in jQuery/JS